# Deleting Text in Parentheses in Python

Tags: python

I have imported a **csv** file in **Python**. I'm trying to remove text present in parentheses in that file.

*I have written the following code:*

```
import csv


with open('example.csv', 'r') as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)

#for line in csv_reader:
    #print(line)


    def a(test_str):
        ret = ''
        skip1c = 0
        skip2c = 0
        for i in test_str:
            if i == '[':
                skip1c += 1
            elif i == '(':
                skip2c += 1
            elif i == ']' and skip1c > 0:
                skip1c -= 1
            elif i == ')' and skip2c > 0:
                skip2c -= 1
            elif skip1c == 0 and skip2c == 0:
                ret += i
        return ret

        x = csv_reader
        x = a(x)
    for line in csv_reader:
        print(line)
```

*Here are a couple of lines from my output:*

```
['CompanyA (CA)']
['CompanyB']
['CompanyC']
['CompanyD (CD)']
['CompanyE (CE)']
```

As you can see, the text in the parentheses is still there. The code doesn't seem to have worked on the file.

I would like to remove the whole word between the parentheses. For instance, the output for "CompanyA (CA)" should only be **CompanyA**, not **CompanyA CA**.

*The following is an example from part of the code above, which does provide the expected result.*

```
    def a(test_str):
ret = ''
skip1c = 0
skip2c = 0
for i in test_str:
    if i == '[':
        skip1c += 1
    elif i == '(':
        skip2c += 1
    elif i == ']' and skip1c > 0:
        skip1c -= 1
    elif i == ')'and skip2c > 0:
        skip2c -= 1
    elif skip1c == 0 and skip2c == 0:
        ret += i
return ret

x = "ewq[a [(b] ([c))]] This is a sentence. (once a day) [twice a day]"
x = a(x)
print x
print repr(x)
```

*Here is the output from that code*:

```
    ewq This is a sentence.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you for your time :)

Comment: You def the function but don't call it? Check your indentation

Answer (score 4):

You can do that using regular expression. The below code should work.

```
import re

input_text = 'ewq[a [(b] ([c))]] This is a sentence. (once a day) [twice a day]'
print re.sub(r'[\(\[]+.*?[\)\]]+', '', input_text)
```

The above code works for any inputs. Please find the code below with the inputs in first block.

```
csv_reader = ['CompanyA (CA)', 'CompanyC', 'CompanyD (CD)']

for line in csv_reader:
    print re.sub(r'[\(\[]+.*?[\)\]]+', '', line)
```

Comment: Hi Praveen, thank you for your reply. My problem is within the first block of code I posted. The second block of code was to show that the code works.

Comment: Hi @OnThaRise, the code works for any inputs. Please find my latest edit.

Comment: Thank you Praveen. Your code works with a list of name that I would manually input in Python. If the file is a CSV file, would it be the same code?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the built-in `find` and `rfind` and slicing. From the beginning to an opening brace plus the string from the first closing brace after first opening brace.

```
def a(ts):
  while '[' in ts:
    ts=ts[:ts.rfind('[')]+ts[ts.find(']',ts.rfind('['))+1:]
  while '(' in ts:
    ts=ts[:ts.rfind('(')]+ts[ts.find(')',ts.rfind('('))+1:]
  return ts

x = "ewq[a [(b] ([c))]] This is a sentence. (once a day) [twice a day]"
x = a(x)
print x
```